# Is jQuery supposed to be used only in the ready event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read code the uses jQuery outside of the ready handler, what are the drawbacks, if any to using it this way? For whatever reason I feel uncomfortable with it coded this way.

Inline script from and ASP.NET MVC View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo() {
        if ($("#checkAll").attr("checked")) {
            $(".setColumns").attr("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $(".setColumns").attr("checked", false);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: The reason of using jQuery within the DOM ready handler is that event binding will only work when the element is present — if your DOM is not ready, your element may not be present and therefore the event may not be bound. You are of course free to define functions outside the handler.

Comment: Any element manipulation. Not just event binding. Elements must exist before they can be manipulated.

Comment: So long as your `foo` function is guaranteed to be called after DOMReady has fired, there is nothing wrong with your code at all.

Comment: I would feel uncomfortable adding functions to the global scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't really any drawbacks. It's just that you need to wait for the DOM element to be loaded before it can be manipulated. For example, if you had code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log($('#el').html());
</script>

<div id="el">Text</div>
```

The function would not return a value because the `div` was not yet loaded.

Comment: Great illustration of the concept :) you beat us hehe.

Answer (score 1):

It is not.
The only reason why some people run it inside the `document.ready` handler, is because at that time, they can be sure the `DOM tree` is completely loaded, and your queries will return the correct results.

However, if you put your script tags underneath all elements, you normally would not have any issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of using jQuery within the DOM ready handler is that event binding will only work when the element is present — if your DOM is not ready, your element may not be present and therefore the event may not be bound.

It is the same problem that people face when trying to bind events to dynamically loaded content without the `.on()` selector, for example — if the element is not initially present, events will not be bound to it.

p/s: You are of course free to define functions outside the handler.

Comment: I wish you would have posted the answer first along with the comment.